# Convert datetime to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, date-conversion

I am working on dates in a query and am seeing some unexpected behavior. I want to convert a `datetime` to `dd-mm-yyyy` format but seem to be unable to get the right result.
On my Dutch machine

I have the following statement:

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME =  '2014-08-25 00:00:00.000'
SELECT FORMAT (@datetime, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

I expect  `25-08-2014`

However, I get `25-00-2014`

Why is this happening and is there a way to get the correct output?

Comment: Have you tried using dd-MM-yyyy ?

Comment: The correct format is just a DATETIME being sent to the presentation layer, at which point you then format the visual presentation of the date.

Comment: Capitalize `mm` to `MM`

Comment: `mm` is minutes, not months. In any case `datetime` and the other date types have no format, they're binary values. It's a *lot* better to just return them to the client and let the *client* format that date value any way it wants

Comment: You really should leave formatting to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MM` not `mm`, since `mm` represents minutes, not months.

```
SELECT FORMAT(@datetime, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to get this is :
Replace getdate() with your date column.

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)
```

Output:

```
21-12-2023
```

Comment: This is the better answer in T-SQL compare to the slothful FORMAT function.  Here's some proof of the claim that CONVERT for this type of thing is almost 28 times faster than FORMAT.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-format-dates-in-sql-server-hint-dont-use-format  I'd also use CHAR(10) instead of VARCHAR with the unwritten default for length.